# If register is equal to 0 then

Tags: assembly, mips

Trying to make a simple if statement for a school assignment.

```
.data
Origin:
    .asciiz "X and Y are at the origin!!!" # string statment for the origin 
inputX:
    .asciiz "What is the x coordinate?"

test:
    .asciiz "this is a test"
.text


main: 
la $a0, inputX #puts the inputX string into address 0
li $v0, 4 # prints a string at address 0
syscall

li $v0 , 5 # reads an input integer
syscall 

move $s0, $v0# moves the value from the input integer into $s0 (x value)



beqz $s0, EndIf # should be if input we entered was 0 than go to EndIf label



li $v0, 10
syscall

EndIf:  la $a0, test #print out our test string
li $v0, 4
syscall
```

From what I understand. The beqz checks if the $s0 is zero. From that it should go to my label.

This is the part that confuses me. Where does this label go? How does it decide when we are not in the label and want to go back to original code?

Basically if my input for x is 0 I want it to print out my "test" string

Comment: only takes a few seconds to write a c function, compile and disassemble to see how the compiler does it...

Answer (score 0):

Branches in assembly are not like subroutines.  Once you branch to a line number, you're now at that line number and you continue increasing the program counter from there.  So, once you BEQZ to Endif:, you're now at Endif, you'll print that string and run off into uninitialized memory land.  There's no mechanism to return.

Consider the following:

```
.data
IF_STRING: .asciiz "IF\n"
ELSE_STRING: .asciiz "ELSE\n"
END_STRING: .asciiz "END\n"

.text
main:
  li $s0,2
  bnez $s0,ELSE

  la $a0,IF_STRING
  li $v0,4
  syscall

  b END

ELSE:
  la $a0,ELSE_STRING
  li $v0,4
  syscall

  #b END is implicit here -- you simply fall straight through

END:
  la $a0,END_STRING
  li $v0,4
  syscall

  li $v0,10
  syscall
```

If you set $s0 to 0, you'll go through the "IF" portion of the code -- if it isn't zero it will jump to the "ELSE" portion of the code.  There's no returning, so to get to the next part of the program you can branch directly to the END label.  In the ELSE portion, there's no need to branch as it would just branch to the next line (and waste a bunch of time doing so).